# How to handle '#' in url for google maps

Tags: javascript, html, maps

I am doing integration of google maps with my website for mobile. Whenever i pass an address to the url which contains '#', it shows the address before the occurance of '#'

Example: if the address is test1#test2 and i pass it to the google url, in the map it shows test1.

URL i am using is "http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=" + add" where add is the variable

Comment: Are you forgetting to URL-encode the address?

Comment: I am not encoding the address. Can you help me out with this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hash (#) is a specific token in a URI (a/k/a URL). It means that you're looking for part of a page and not a whole resource. Typically, when you need to include a token that would cause issues in parsing a URL (such as a "$" or a "/"), you should "URI-encode" the token. This results in something like `%20` (a space), or `%2F` ("/"). You probably just need to URI-encode your hash as `%23`.

Chances are you should be URI-encoding the entire address you want to send, not just hashes. There are many options for doing this. JavaScript even has a built-in function that does the job ([encodeURIComponent()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp)).

Comment: Yes. You can place an encoded URL in an href. (Sorry, I tried to show an example, but the SO link parsing failed me!)